# Lockdown pro suddenly stopped working. Is there anyway to un/reinstall?

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, screen, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I had Lockdown pro app installed and everything was working fine until the latest update from Samsung which brought some new features such as battery app optimizing.

Now the Lockdown pro no longer works and can never be accessed by the dialing code as well. I also have the option to hide the app icon with disable the uninstalling option for it.

So my question is how can i uninstall this app?

Comment: Is it been given sys admin status?

Comment: Yes unfortunately.

Comment: You can let the developer know of what happened here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2679305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the app has been given system administrator permissions, follow the steps:

1. Go to Settings –> Security –> Device administrators.
2. Here, you can see the various apps checked for Device Adminstrator access, just uncheck the app that and Deactivate it in the next screen.
3. Now you can go ahead and uninstall the app normally.